# In React Login component Firebase Login signup is working but when I am trying to send a reset password Link then is Not sending to email

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reset-password

In React Login component Firebase login signup is working but when I am trying to send a reset password Link then it is not working. there is no getting email value from the field, but sign-in is working.
So unable to send the reset password link in my email.

**Login Submit Button : it's working:**

```js
 const handleToSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const email = event.target.email.value;
    const password = event.target.password.value;
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
}
```

**Reset password Function code:  it's not working:**

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

        const resetPassword = async (event) => {
            const email = event.target.email.value
            if (email) {
                await sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
                toast.success(`Check your Email ⮞ ${email}`);
            } else {
                toast.warn('Enter Email  ☹ ');
            }
        }

<!-- end snippet -->
```

**My Email input field: it's working for login but not for reset password**

```
<Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
      <Form.Control type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
</Form.Group>
```

**Reset Click Button:  it's not working:**

```
    <button onClick={resetPassword}> Reset Password </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using firebase v9.

So you should pass `auth` as parameter to the function:

```
import { getAuth, sendPasswordResetEmail } from  "firebase/auth"; 

const auth = getAuth();
sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email)
  .then(() => {
    // Password reset email sent!
    // show the toast
  })
```